# A game within a list of lists using Python

Tags: python, list

[Picture of the two dimensional model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msXLg.jpg)

I am not sure where to go about with this program. I am to make a random function that calculates a number (1-4) then whatever number the output is, an "electron" will come out of the "S" in the picture and go in the direction according the the random number. If the "electron" reaches an "E", it escapes. If the "electron" reaches an R it is reflected back to the position right before hand. If the "electron" hits an A it is absorbed. I am to run 500 "electrons" through this program all starting at the S with 500 moves each and count how many "electrons" where absorbed, escaped and ones that neither escaped or were absorbed. The approach I made to this was to make a list of lists. with the first list being the 1st row in the picture, the 2nd being the 2nd row and so on.. Does anyone know of a better or nice approach for me to make with this program? If so I would greatly apreciate it..

Comment: I'm a little confused by the mechanics of your game. So the electron can only move in a straight line in 4 directions until something is hit? Can you elaborate more on how the electron moves in the space and reacts to different squares?

Comment: so the electron has 500 moves. Each move is either up, down, left, or right. The direction it moves each time is totally random. if it moves to an empty space it is obviously fine, if it moves to an R space it is reflected back to the space it came from. If it hits an A it is absorbed and disappears, if it hits an E it escapes. Once the electron is either absorbed or escaped, a new one comes out of the S and pretty much starts all over. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I attached a picture of what the list of lists would look like. I am to run 500 particles through the whole thing with each having a possibility of 500 moves.

Comment: Can you post some code with what you have tried so far?

Comment: I posted some of the code below as an answer @JasonYost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a list of lists, with counters to keep track of position would be useful for what you are trying to do. For example:

```
list_game[10][2]
```

would be your starting position.
You would also likely have 5 unique values in your list for the 5 types of tiles you have in your game (A,S,E,R, blank).

For position as:

```
list_game[i][j]
```

Going up and down would increase/decrease i, while moving left and right would do the equivalent to j.

Comment: Alright, that's the approach i had. Just wanted to see if there would be a better or easier one, Thank you!

Comment: Since speed will not be a major issue(small list size), this seems to be the most simple option (faster solutions using matrices and arrays would be faster but would not necessarily be useful given the small scale). If my answer and follow up met your expectations, would you mind selecting them as the selected answer?